# Cordova nfc plugin write text to nfc card

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, nfc

I am testing with cordova to write a simple text to a card. On a bootstrap button i have

```
onclick="write_btn();"
```

And in index.js i have added

```
    function write_btn(){
    alert("Write some to card");
    var message = [
    ndef.textRecord("hello, world of NFC"),
    ];
    var sMsg;
    nfc.write(message, 
    function(){sMsg="good";alert("Write Succes");}, 
    function(){sMsg="fals";alert("Nothing got written");}
            );
    console.log("Writing is: "+sMsg);
    alert("Writing is: "+sMsg);
}
```

But nothing is written, just the alert. If i have just the alert("...") within the function write_btn it's triggered. ndef is a global var, right?

regards

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you need to call ndef.write(message) when a NFC tag is in range of the phone. The best way to do this is to call write from inside the nfcEvent Handler.

```
# www/js/index.js
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        nfc.addNdefListener(app.onNfc);
    },
    onNfc: function(nfcEvent) {
        // message is an array of records
        var message = [
            ndef.textRecord("hello, world")
        ];
        nfc.write(message, app.onWriteSuccess);
    },
    onWriteSuccess: function() {
        alert("Wrote message to tag.");
    }
};
```